# Como preencher variável php via jquery/ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de mensagens em php + mysql e na "caixa de entrada" estou exibindo as mensagens em formatado de tabela, utilizando o plugin datatables.

Acontece que quero abrir a mensagem num modal quando o usuário clicar no assunto. Porém ainda não consegui encontrar uma maneira de "pegar" o ID da mensagem clicada, fazer a consulta daquela mensagem no banco e então abrir os dados no modal.

Parte do código da caixa de entrada e do "link" para o modal no assunto:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
    $phpdate = strtotime( $row['criada'] );
    $mysqldate = date( 'H:i d-m-Y', $phpdate );
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['denome'] . "</td>";
    echo '<td><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-leremail" style="cursor: pointer;">' . $row['assunto'] . '</a></td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['mensagem'] . '</td>';
    echo "<td>" . $mysqldate . "</td>";
    echo '<td></td>';
    echo "</tr>";
} ?>
```

Já pesquisei várias maneiras mas ainda não consegui entender muito bem como fazer isso com jquery, ajax, etc, pois sei o básico.

Teoricamente, se eu conseguisse uma forma simples de "pegar" o ID da mensagem, seria só consultar então no banco e carregar os dados no modal, não?

Answer (score 1):

Adicione uma div no lugar onde vc deseja que exiba as informaçoes dentro do modal:

```
<div id='iddeumadivvaziadentrodomodal'></div
```

Adicione o onclick chamando uma função js passando como paramentro o id:

```
echo "<td><a onclick(carregardados(". $row['id'] .")) data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modal-leremail' style='cursor: pointer;'>" . $row['assunto'] . "</a></td>";
```

Depois Voce cria essa função enviando o id via ajax para o php, passando o id e um codigo como parametro.

```
function carregardados(id){
var result = "",cod = 2;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: 'buscardados.php',
        data: {id,cod},
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Falha":textStatus);
        },
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            result += "<div>"+data['assunto']+"</div>";


            $('#iddeumadivvaziadentrodomodal').html(result);
        }
    }); };
```

por ultimo vc criar o arquivo php

```
if($cod == 2){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
       $db = conn();
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM tuatabela WHERE id = $id";
       $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
       $arr  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

       return $arr;
}
```

pronto todas as informações que voce quizer inserir vc coloca no success do ajaz com o html que vc quizer.

Comment: Não funcionou... Usei o mesmo código e nada acontece... :(

Comment: faça verificação onde está a falha, debug o codigo, encontre onde está o error de nao está funcionando eu uso em varios projetos e funciona muito bem, veja se o caminho está correto, veja se ta retornando alguma coisa, verifique desde o js ao php.